# Segmentation fault while creating a Stack VM

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a VM which will run simple stuff for now. However, after compilation, I tried running it but got a segmentation fault. There are 4 files : `stack-vm.h`, `stack-vm.cpp`, `main.cpp`, `makefile`.

stack-vm.h :

```
#ifndef STACK_VM_H
  #define STACK_VM_H

  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>

  //type definitions
  typedef int32_t i32;

  class StackVM {

  private:
    i32 pc = 100; // program counter
    i32 sp = 0; // stack pointer
    std::vector<i32> memory;
    i32 typ = 0;
    i32 dat = 0;
    i32 running = 1;

    i32 getType(i32 instruction);
    i32 getData(i32 instruction);
    void fetch();
    void decode();
    void execute();
    void doPrimitive();

  public:
    StackVM();
    void run();
    void loadProgram(std::vector<i32> prog);

  };

#endif
```

stack-vm.cpp :

```
    #include "stack-vm.h"

StackVM::StackVM() {
  memory.reserve(1000000);
}

i32 StackVM::getType(i32 instruction) {
  i32 type = 0xc0000000;
  type = (type & instruction) >> 30;
  return type;
}

i32 StackVM::getData(i32 instruction) {
  i32 data = 0x3fffffff;
  data = data & instruction;
  return data;
}
void StackVM::fetch() {
  pc++;
}

void StackVM::decode() {
  typ = getType(memory[pc]);
  dat = getData(memory[pc]);
}

void StackVM::execute() {
  if (typ == 0 || typ == 2) {
    sp++;
    memory[sp] = dat;
  } else {
    doPrimitive();
  }
}

void StackVM::doPrimitive() {
  switch (dat) {
    case 0: // halt
      std::cout << "halt" << std::endl;
      running = 0;
      break;

    case 1: // add
      std::cout << "add " << memory[sp - 1] << " " << memory[sp] << std::endl;
      memory[sp - 1] = memory[sp - 1] + memory[sp];
      break;
  }
}

void StackVM::run() {
  pc -= 1;
  while (running) {
    fetch();
    decode();
    execute();
    std::cout << "tos: " << memory[sp] << std::endl;
  }
}

void StackVM::loadProgram(std::vector<i32> prog) {
  for (i32 i = 0; 1 < prog.size(); i++) {
    memory[pc + i] = prog[i];
  }
}
```

main.cpp :

```
    #include "stack-vm.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  StackVM vm;
  std::vector<i32> prog{3, 4, 0x40000001, 0x40000000};
  vm.loadProgram(prog);

  return 0;
}
```

makefile :

```
        CFLAGS=-std=c++11

    all: stack-vm

    stack-vm: stack-vm.o main.o
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) stack-vm.o main.o -o stack-vm

    main.o: main.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp

    stack-vm.o: stack-vm.h stack-vm.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c stack-vm.cpp

    clean:
        rm -f *.o stack-vm
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Start by catching the crash in a debugger to learn when and where in your code the crash happens. Also examine the values of all involved variables at that point. If you still can't figure it out yourself, then please update your question to include all those details.

Comment: `memory` is empty when `loadProgram` is called, so you are accessing elements out of bounds. `reserve` doesn't add any items, You probably confused it with `resize`.

Comment: @rafix07 No it's actually `reserve` which is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line:

```
for (i32 i = 0; 1 < prog.size(); i++)
```

is incorrect, and should be i, not 1.

In addition reserve sets the capacity, not the size of the vector. You should use resize.

Comment: Either it's `resize` or `reserve`, still there's not output.

Comment: you should use resize

Comment: no output as in no printout ? That's because you load, but don't call run